# How to update a dropdown list on parent page after closing modal window

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Okay, so I have an ASP.NET WebForms page with C# code behind. I have a dropdown list bound to a data table in SQL. I am adding a maintenance screen (modal) for users to manage the data in the table/dropdown (add/inactivate records). The user clicks a '+' button next to the dropdown list, the modal comes up, they add or remove a record, and then close the modal. Upon closing (in the 'Close:' property) I'd like to have the dropdown list on the parent page rebind to the updated table data, preferrably without posting back.

I'm having a tough time doing this, anyone have any suggestions?

Code behind to bind drop down to original data on parent Page_Load:

```
var fundingTypes = client.GetFundingTypeAll();
var onlyActiveFundingTypes = fundingTypes.FindAll(x => x.IsActive == true);
EncryptionHelper.EncryptProperties(onlyActiveFundingTypes);
ddlFundingType.DataSource = onlyActiveFundingTypes;
ddlFundingType.DataValueField = "Id_X";
ddlFundingType.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlFundingType.DataBind();
```

Could this be done using a WebMethod call to the code behind to do the rebind?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a UpdatePanel arround the DropDownList and rebind the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use an `UpdatePanel` that can cause a partial post back or use AJAX calls that can bind the new data on your page (via templating).

I am guessing option #2 (AJAX with templating) will not be a viable solution for you as it would involve re-working the approach to your UI.

Comment: Glad this answer helped you, feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: Not enough karma...to do anything on this website... :)

Comment: @Matt - soon you will :-)